# Is there any way to prevent ncurses based programs from running?

Tags: ruby, shell, unix, virtual, ncurses

Hey there, I'm building a remote shell server that interfaces between a text-only client and a virtual shell.

It works perfectly when using regular shell commands, but the first thing that people try after that is vim, which promptly drives my server crazy and can't even be closed remotely.

Is there any way to detect ncurses based programs and prevent them from running in my special shell?

(the server is ruby, but any system command will do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare the capabilities your shell has, by setting the TERM environment variable to the correct value. For instance, if your shell has the same capabilities as the vt100 terminal, export TERM to the correct value, and programs like vim will respect that.

To run vim in vt100-mode, try:

```
TERM=vt100 vim
```

You could also try:

```
export TERM=dumb
```

The trick is to find a terminal that corresponds to the capabilities of what you are creating. There is a lot to choose from. On my system (Arch Linux) this gives me a long list of choices:

```
find /usr/share/terminfo
```

You might be able to find a terminal specification that corresponds to what your program can handle.

Alternatively, you may want to consider implementing terminal emulation for ansi or vt100:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

Best of luck!

Comment: I also found this page, which has a friendly approach and nice overview of escape codes: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes Escape sequences can be surprisingly entertaining. To reset the terminal, for example, just echo -en "\033c"